# Type cast to Generic Type for ShowViewmodel

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, mvvmcross

I am using a complex statemachine to handle certain things in parts of my app , that require state management .. however i have an issue , the ViewModel type is saved as a string. Any ideas how to turn a "Type" into the required TViewModel, i have a feeling im doing something silly and missing the point

```
internal void Navigate(Type viewModelType)
    {

        T newT1 = (T)(viewModelType);
       ShowViewModel<TVIEWMODEL>();
    }
```

Comment: What is T in your example code?

Comment: So you want to call a generic method without having a generic constraint 'available'?

Comment: basically i have the type which i retreived from a string name,  and i want to convert it into a TViewModel , so T can be different things but it must inherit from a base class MvxViewModel

Comment: You cannot convert a *type* to an *object instance*. An option would be to create a new ViewModel instance based on the type.

Comment: You don't have an instance of TViewModel, just its type. What good is that supposed to do? You could create an instance with `Activator.CreateInstance()` if the related class has a standard constructor, but that probably wouldn't help either.

Comment: It turns out that i was being dumb, my guess it was monday morningness .. basically  i failed to check if the showviewmodel method had a generic method that took a type in as a parameter .. i was so focussed on the genericness .. thanks all

Answer (score 1):

all i had to do was use,

```
 ShowViewModel(viewModelType);
```

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to work out exactly what you are trying to do

What is `T` ?

What is `TViewModel` ?

What does the signature for `ShowViewModel` look like?

However if you are trying to call a generic method using a runtime type you can use [MakeGenericMethod](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCIQFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Fsystem.reflection.methodinfo.makegenericmethod%2528v%3Dvs.110%2529.aspx&ei=dkEZVdXtHNKraa7SgegF&usg=AFQjCNH7vVxUCgoe0AxW_NN2EmOlw4uWtw&bvm=bv.89381419,d.d2s)

```
var method = GetType().GetMethod("ShowViewModel");
var method2 = method.MakeGenericMethod(viewModelType);
method2.Invoke(this,null);
```